# Text between two tags (

Tags: php, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

please help me, i need script which select text between tag's *( `<DIV id="image">any text in source soce</DIV>` )* on loaded page with file_get_contents.

A friend advised me, but it does not work:

```
$vyber = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all("'<span>(.*?)</span>'si", $vyber, $get);
```

Comment: Your expression looks for `<span>` while your stated requirement is stuff inside `<div>` (not to mention the lack of an `id='image'` attribute)

Comment: So your friend advices you to search for spans when looking for divs? :o

Comment: Try querypath with `print qp($url)->find("div#image")->text();`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether regex is the best solution here.

You cannot create perefect regex (or you can but it will take much time) which will cover

```
<div somethingelse="" id="image"></div>
<div id="Image></div>
<div id=Image></div>
```

What I would do is using html dom parser
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

The code would be:

```
<?php
    require_once('DomParserFile.php'); //Replace this ofc
    $Html = file_get_html('http://YourUrlHere.com/'); //html not file :)
    $ContentInThisDiv = $Html->fing('div#image')->src;
    echo($ContentInThisDiv);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://urlhere.com');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

    foreach($nodes as $val):
        $id = $val->getElementByid('image');
        foreach($id as $content){
            $text = $content->nodeValue;
        endforeach;
        echo $text . '</br>\n';
    endforeach;
```

This should work although not tested.